# Replace text with html code in datatable after loading data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

As explained in the title, I have a function that loads a datatable with data.
A column is filled with true/false/empty which I would like to replace with HTML code depending on the boolean result.

The table is loaded with an object array as follows:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < data.stazioni.length; i++) {
                stations.push(new Object());
                stations[i].stationName = data.stazioni[i].nome;
                if (data.stazioni[i].zone.length > 0)
                    stations[i].z1 = data.stazioni[i].zone[0].enabled;
                else
                    stations[i].z1 = "";
                if (data.stazioni[i].zone.length > 1)
                    stations[i].z2 = data.stazioni[i].zone[1].enabled;
                else
                    stations[i].z2 = "";
                if (data.stazioni[i].zone.length > 2)
                    stations[i].z3 = data.stazioni[i].zone[2].enabled;
                else
                    stations[i].z3 = "";
                zone.push(data.stazioni[i].zone);
            }
            stationTable.clear().rows.add(stations).draw();
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like, you're looking for [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). Can't post exact code, since you didn't mention which exactly HTML you expect in place of true/false/empty.

Comment: Well I was planning to insert a red cirle in case of false and a green one in case of true, so <img src="...">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea give by @user11299053, I used `columns.render`.

During the table declaration I specified for the specified column what to do with the data inside the cell, and rendered as HTML.

```
"columns": [
            {
                'data': 'zone1', 'sClass': 'zone1', "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    var zone_html = "";
                    if (data) {
                        var temp = data.split(';');
                        temp[2] = temp[2] === "-1" ? "" : temp[2];
                        zone_html = '<img src="../images/enabled_' + temp[0] + '.png"> <img src="../images/program_' + temp[1] + '.png"> ' + temp[2];
                    }
                    return zone_html;
                }
            },
```

This worked out quite well.
THanks for your help.